# How to import SQL v8 (2000) DB in v12 (2014) Server

Tags: sql-server-2014

I made a backup of a db on one server and tried importing it on another server.
I got the error message saying they are incompatible.

I'm currently running SQL Express v12 on windows server 2012.

What are my possible actions now? Can I deinstall the SQL server and install an older version? Importing on SQL Server v10 (2008) works. I tried that on a different machine.

Can I somehow downgrade the SQL server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is you can't do what you are attempting to do.  You will need to do an interim DB upgrade to a higher version and then another to the final version.  The full set of instructions can be found [here](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2014/sql-select-steps-migrate-sql-server-2000-sql-server-2014).

Comment: Did I understood the article correctly that I should import/export using SQL 2008 (v10) in a step in between?

Comment: Yes. 2000 is so ancient that there is no way to import anymore. I  think MS policy is to support 2 generations back. You are - well, ancient.